# Architecture: Organizing and accessing 1..n optional instances of an interface in a single struct

Tags: go, architecture

Let's say I have an Interface `Animal`, instances of which are saved in a separate struct `Human`. There are multiple types of animals that implement the interface. Each human can have 1..n of these `Animals`. Access from the human to the animals should be as simple as possible. My initial idea was to have a map [string]Animal with a constant for each animal. I feel like this is a bit clunky. Is there a better way of doing this?

Here's a simplified example of what I currently have. The code I'm working on has 20+ types that implement the interface, while each instance of the parent only has a couple.

https://go.dev/play/p/Rw4iMjHbMQF

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
)

const (
   COW = "Cow"
   DOG = "Dog"
   CAT = "Cat"
)

func main() {
   h1 := Human{Animals: map[string]Animal{
      COW: Cow{},
      DOG: Dog{},
      CAT: Cat{},
   }}

   h2 := Human{Animals: map[string]Animal{
      CAT: Cat{},
   }}

   if cow, ok := h1.Animals[COW]; ok {
      cow.(Cow).EatGrass()
   }

   if cow, ok := h2.Animals[CAT]; ok {
      cow.(Cat).Scratch("bingo")
   }
}

type Human struct {
   Animals map[string]Animal
}

type Animal interface {
   Speak()
}

type Cow struct {
}

func (c Cow) Speak() {
   fmt.Println("moo")
}

func (c Cow) EatGrass() {
   fmt.Println("munch")
}

type Dog struct {
}

func (d Dog) Speak() {
   fmt.Println("bark")
}

func (d Dog) Fetch(ball string) string {
   return ball
}

type Cat struct {
}

func (c Cat) Speak() {
   fmt.Println("meow")
}

func (c Cat) Scratch(human string) {
   fmt.Println(human + ": ouch")
}
```

Comment: It's not clear why the interface even exists. You never use it. Just declare fields of the appropriate concrete type.

Comment: @Peter It's a simplified example of what I'm working with. I didn't want to make the example too long, which is why I'm not really using the interface. Instead of three, I have 20+ types that implement the interface, of which an instance of the parent only has a couple each. Having a field for each type is not a good solution imo. Updating my question.

Comment: With the way you implement it, a Human can have at most one of each type of animal.  Is that what you want? What is wrong with []Animal? What is the ultimate goal here? What will you do with those Animals.

Comment: @BurakSerdar `a Human can have at most one of each type of animal. Is that what you want? ` - Yes. That is not a problem. `What is wrong with []Animal?` - to access any animal, (to my knowledge) I would have to iterate the slice each time and switch-case the type of each animal until I find the one I'm looking for. My dream solution would be a dynamic one, where I don't have to access the map, then cast each time I want to access, but without having a field for each type. Probably not possible though, thanks for your input anyways.